# Como criar a função do alert em javascript para um menu especifico da página?

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho uma página em PHP onde quero implementar uma alerta em JavaScript para quando o usuário clicar no menu "Cria um chamado"retornar uma mensagem para o usuário. Eu fiz a implementação usando o alert(), porém o alerta retorna quando a página é atualizada e não é bem isso que eu quero que o alert() faça na página.

Este é o meu PHP.

```html
//  Create ticket
      if (Session::haveRight("ticket", CREATE)) {
         $menu['create_ticket']['id']      = "menu2";
         $menu['create_ticket']['default'] = '/front/helpdesk.public.php?create_ticket=1';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Retorne uma mensagem para o usuário ao clicar!");</script>';
         $menu['create_ticket']['title']   = __s('Create a ticket')
         $menu['create_ticket']['content'] = array(true);
      }
```

Devido ao código exceder o limite de caractere postarei abaixo o código completo da página.

Link: [Código Completo](https://github.com/glpi-project/glpi/blob/master/inc/html.class.php)

Código fonte da página gerada em HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

</script>
<a href="#" onclick="$('#loadbookmark').dialog('open');">
  <img src="/glpi/pics/bookmark.png" title="Carregar um favorito" alt="Carregar um favorito" class="button-icon">
</a>
</li>
<li id="help_link">
  <a href="http://glpi-project.org/help-helpdesk" target="_blank" title="Ajuda">
    <img src="/glpi/pics/help.png" title="Ajuda" alt="Ajuda" class="button-icon">
  </a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="c_recherche"></div>
</div>
<div id="c_menu">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Retorne uma mensagem para o usuário ao clicar!");
  </script>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li id="menu1"><a href="/glpi/front/helpdesk.public.php" title="Home" class="itemP">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu2"><a href="/glpi/front/helpdesk.public.php?create_ticket=1" title="Cria um chamado" class="itemP">Cria um chamado</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu3"><a href="/glpi/front/ticket.php" title="Chamados" class="itemP">Chamados</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu4"><a href="/glpi/front/reservationitem.php" title="Reservas" class="itemP">Reservas</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu5"><a href="/glpi/front/helpdesk.faq.php" title="FAQ" class="itemP">FAQ</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    < /html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas não estou conseguindo implementar a função que chame o alerta para somente o item deste menu e não para página toda. Alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Qual é o HTML desse _"item"_ que referes? podes explicar melhor a pergunta?

Comment: Sergio! Acrescentei o meu código HTML no corpo da pergunta.

Comment: Renato, reabri. Podes explicar melhor o que o utilizador deve fazer/clicar e o que gostavas que acontecesse?

Comment: Eu quero que ao clicar no menu2 em"Criar chamado' o usuário receba uma mensagem em caixa de texto eu usei o alert() para tentar fazer este procedimento, mas ele retorna para toda página.

Answer (score 2):

Seria algo assim?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mostraAlerta() {
        alert("Retorne uma mensagem para o usuário ao clicar!");
    }
</script>
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="menu1"><a href="/glpi/front/helpdesk.public.php" title="Home" class="itemP">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu2"><a href="/glpi/front/helpdesk.public.php?create_ticket=1" title="Cria um chamado" class="itemP" onclick="mostraAlerta();">Cria um chamado</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu3"><a href="/glpi/front/ticket.php" title="Chamados" class="itemP">Chamados</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu4"><a href="/glpi/front/reservationitem.php" title="Reservas" class="itemP">Reservas</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu5"><a href="/glpi/front/helpdesk.faq.php" title="FAQ" class="itemP">FAQ</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Eu tentei fazer desta forma Michellle, mas como eu chamo o alert só para o menu2 e não para toda página? Dê uma olhada em meu código fonte da página.

Comment: Nesse caso é no HTML, se eu entendi o que você quer corretamente. Já está na resposta.

Comment: echo <script type="text/javascript">
    function mostraAlerta() {
        alert("Retorne uma mensagem para o usuário ao clicar!");
    }
</script>           Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in

Comment: Ah, faltava esse detalhe na sua pergunta. Explica melhor lá em cima que alguém pode te ajudar. Não dá pra gente adivinhar que você quer mudar o *código que gera* o HTML que você postou.

Comment: O que seria ideal postar o meu código fonte PHP ou o código fonte da página em HTML?

Comment: Seria ideal postar o link que mandou o GitHub, com a linha marcada que se encontra essa função que gera o código. Não é uma alteração tão simples, pra alguém sugerir a resposta precisa ver mais do que um trecho de códigos que postou atualmente.

Comment: O problema Michelle que o código é muito extenso é excede o limite de caracteres,mas no entanto vou fazer o seguinte postar uma parte do código com o link do código completo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48794/discussion-between-renato-lazaro-and-michelle-akemi).

Comment: Ainda não conseguir implementar o alert com as informações da resposta acima.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo código fonte da página gerada em HTML que você mostrou, parece que você utiliza o jQuery na página(acredito eu):

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#loadbookmark').dialog('open');">
```

se for o caso e você queira executar um alert() para o campo:

```
<li id="menu2"><a href="/glpi/front/helpdesk.public.php?create_ticket=1" title="Cria um chamado" class="itemP">Cria um chamado</a>
</li>
```

você pode adicionar no cabeçalho ou rodapé da página o seguinte código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#menu2').click(function(){
    alert("Retorne uma mensagem para o usuário ao clicar!");
  }) 
});
</script>
```

se não utiliza o jQuery eu acredito que o exemplo da Michelle funcionaria perfeitamente.

Mas você tem que levar em consideração se você quer mostrar o alerta e redirecionar o usuário, se for mostrar informação do que seria aquele link do menu, talvez implementar algo como o `Tooltip` do [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) seria uma boa ideia.

Obs.:

Se for imprimir o código direto do php, não esqueça de colocar o código entre aspas simples `''` caso o código javascript ou html tiver aspas duplas `""`

Comment: Herbert-hudson! Executei conforme orientado em meu código PHP, porém retorna erro de na linha 39. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in on line 39. Dê uma olha acrescentei no cabeçalho do meu PHP https://gist.github.com/Nerato/fc5eccbf4febca4ea5215224c8e66760

Comment: Renato, o que está faltando aí que você esqueceu de usar o `echo`, e se esse arquivo php que for renderizar o html então você teria que fazer assim:

Comment: $script = <<<EOF
<scritp type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#menu2').click(function(){
    alert("Retorne uma mensagem para o usuário ao clicar!");
  }) 
});
</script>
EOF;
echo $script;
é um exemplo...

Comment: o erro ` Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in on line 39` se refere que ele não consegue reconhecer o começo do código como php:
<script type="text/javascript">
pois é javascript e você precisa imprimi-lo para o navegador executar...

Comment: agora que percebi que você está querendo editar uma parte de um projeto, o GLPi, só que dessa forma que você quer ai não irá dar certo, primeiro você precisa achar o arquivo que gera a página, simplesmente adicionando isso ai nos arquivos que você passou não irá funcionar

Comment: Este arquivo que lhe passei que gera a página https://gist.github.com/Nerato/fc5eccbf4febca4ea5215224c8e66760

Comment: Herbert Hudson! Funcionou aqui colocando em outra página PHP, porém o alerta aparece e some sozinho eu quero que ele fique na tela ao clicar no meu, como faço?

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo que de uma olhada em Modal Panel: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

você pode colcoar o html do painel na chamada do botão